App crash with wallpaper Capacitorjs plugin
I've been trying to create a Capacitor plugin (under MIT license) for a few weeks that allows you to apply wallpapers on Android. At first, it "works" and applies the wallpaper, but then the app crashes. I'm not a Java programmer, so I've been learning by head-butting.
I've tried a thousand different things: looking at similar repositories, other projects, thread management, etc. Nothing has worked for me.
It's my repository:
https://github.com/Kevinsillo/capacitor-plugin-wallpaper
Logcat in Android Studio:
V  To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 86549773, pluginId: Wallpaper, methodName: setFromURL
V  callback: 86549773, pluginId: Wallpaper, methodName: setFromURL, methodData: {"input":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/ztSE1u9.png","target":"home","display":"fit"}
I  Getting cookies at: 'https://i.imgur.com/ztSE1u9.png'
D  tagSocket(76) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D  app_time_stats: avg=1120.51ms min=5.50ms max=2235.52ms count=2
V  Notifying listeners for event pause
D  No listeners found for event pause
D  App paused
D  Firing change: false
V  Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
D  No listeners found for event appStateChange
D  App stopped
D  Saving instance state!
D  App destroyed
D  Fill dialog is enabled:false, hints=[password, passwordAuto, creditCardNumber, creditCardSecurityCode, creditCardExpirationDate]
D  Starting BridgeActivity
D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorCookies
D  Registering plugin instance: WebView
D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorHttp
D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorSQLite
D  Registering plugin instance: App
D  Registering plugin instance: Filesystem
D  Registering plugin instance: Preferences
D  Registering plugin instance: Wallpaper
W  Unable to read file at path public/plugins
D  Loading app at https://localhost
D  Handling local request: https://localhost/
D  App started
D  Firing change: true
V  Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
D  No listeners found for event appStateChange
D  App resumed
D  eglCreateContext: 0x79635255f2d0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
W  Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
   java.lang.Throwable
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.l(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-506007137:1729)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.g(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-506007137:3003)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.evaluateJavaScript(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-506007137:781)
    at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:893)
    at com.getcapacitor.cordova.MockCordovaWebViewImpl.lambda$eval$0(MockCordovaWebViewImpl.java:193)
    at com.getcapacitor.cordova.MockCordovaWebViewImpl.$r8$lambda$5P7Mo4npmQcOjtTm9tp1elW11Gw(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.getcapacitor.cordova.MockCordovaWebViewImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
I  Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-ByENdsoa.js
D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-D1xy5GdJ.css
W  Expecting binder but got null!
I  Davey! duration=816ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=9255, IntendedVsync=194951992986, Vsync=195651992958, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=195653213800, AnimationStart=195653242400, PerformTraversalsStart=195654070000, DrawStart=195716516100, FrameDeadline=194968659652, FrameInterval=195653027800, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=195723959700, SyncStart=195725505200, IssueDrawCommandsStart=195725531600, SwapBuffers=195745809300, FrameCompleted=195769716600, DequeueBufferDuration=72400, QueueBufferDuration=2102500, GpuCompleted=195769716600, SwapBuffersCompleted=195749755300, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=195745809300, 
D  Handling local request: https://localhost/favicon.ico
D  app_time_stats: avg=380.76ms min=49.85ms max=1004.98ms count=4

